# Sorting IEnumerable in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, ienumerable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sorting an IEnumerable in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12241619/sorting-an-ienumerable-in-linq)

Is it possible to sort this one by not using .ToList()?

Please see codes below.

The code below will result to this output.

```
    { id = 1, name = "sample 1", list = {'a','f','d'}},         
    { id = 5, name = "sample 1", list = {'a','f','c'}},
    { id = 2, name = "sample 1", list = {'g','b'}},
    { id = 4, name = "sample 1", list = {'i','e','h'}},
    { id = 6, name = "sample 1", list = {'d','b','c'}},
    { id = 3, name = "sample 1", list = {'h','i','c'}},
```

Thanks

RJ

```
IEnumerable<extra> eList = new List<extra>()
{
    new extra{ id = 1, text = "a"},
    new extra{ id = 2, text = "g"},
    new extra{ id = 3, text = "i"},
    new extra{ id = 4, text = "e"},
    new extra{ id = 5, text = "f"},
    new extra{ id = 6, text = "d"},
    new extra{ id = 7, text = "c"},
    new extra{ id = 8, text = "h"},
    new extra{ id = 9, text = "b"}
};

IEnumerable<sample> sam = new List<sample>()
{
    new sample{ id = 1, name = "sample 1", list = new List<int>{1,5,6}},
    new sample{ id = 2, name = "sample 2", list = new List<int>{2,9}},
    new sample{ id = 3, name = "sample 3", list = new List<int>{8,3,7}},
    new sample{ id = 4, name = "sample 4", list = new List<int>{3,4,8}},
    new sample{ id = 5, name = "sample 5", list = new List<int>{1,5,7}},
    new sample{ id = 6, name = "sample 6", list = new List<int>{6,9,7}}
};

var sorted = (from d1 in sam
              select new
              {
                  name = d1.name,
                  id = d1.id,
                  list =
                  (
                      from d2 in d1.list
                      join e in eList on d2 equals e.id
                      select e.text
                  ).OrderBy(item => item).ToList()
              }).OrderBy(item => item.list.FirstOrDefault());
```

Comment: BTW your naming convention is painful.

Comment: this is just a practice.... naming is not my concern in here... thanks

Comment: Honestly, for once I think you want `ToList` here. Otherwise your `list` member contains an `IEnumerable`, not a `List`, and every time you enumerate it it will re-perform the join. If you don't mind this, you can listerally just remove the `ToList` call and the ordering will still be the same.

Comment: @Rawling, sorry but its not working.. it doesn't sort the list at all.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Maybe ThenBy will do it?</strike>

```
var sorted = (from d1 in sam 
              select new 
              { 
                  name = d1.name, 
                  id = d1.id, 
                  list = 
                  ( 
                      from d2 in d1.list 
                      join e in eList on d2 equals e.id 
                      select e.text 
                  ).OrderBy(item => item 
              }).ThenBy(item => item.list.FirstOrDefault());
```

I misunderstood the question. Why not just remove the ToList? You probably want to have .ToList() though to prevent sorting each time you access the collection.

Comment: It doesn't work... 'string' does not contain a definition for 'list' and no extension method 'list' accepting a first argument of type 'string'.......

Comment: Oh right. I just edited. Try the new one.

Comment: ) expected... added it in the OrderBy() but got an error... 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>' does not contain a definition for 'ThenBy' and no extension method 'ThenBy' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>'

Comment: Yeah, `ThenBy` makes no sense here as it's the internal enumeration that's ordered, not the external one.

Comment: Wait, what is the problem with just removing the ToList(). It works fine for me.

Comment: It still work without the ToList(). Thanks for the time Stilgar and others... thanks a lot.

Comment: You probably want to have ToList though.

Comment: Wait, it doesn't sort the list in the sample object.  The expected output must be.. 1st sort the list in the sample object then base on the sorted list in the sorted object sort again the whole list in the sample object reference to the sample.list...

Comment: You are right but still you may end up with many more sorts than you expect. Each time a the outer OrderBy needs to compare the values it will execute the sort.

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested your original code without 'ToList' and it sorts the items AND the 'extras' just fine.. Could you elaborate what exactly you want to achieve? Proof:

result of your original code with ToList:

```
1  "sample 1"  a d f  
5  "sample 5"  a c f  
2  "sample 2"  b g  
6  "sample 6"  b c d  
3  "sample 3"  c h i  
4  "sample 4"  e h i
```

result of your code without ToList:

```
1  "sample 1"  a d f   <-- adf is sorted
5  "sample 5"  a c f   <-- also sorted
2  "sample 2"  b g     <-- and here too
6  "sample 6"  b c d   <-- yep
3  "sample 3"  c h i   <-- it is!
4  "sample 4"  e h i   <-- ...
               ^
               |
               \ aabbce is sorted, too
```

looks identical to me :)

As for the general idea, the small problem the same written in LINQ syntax without that "ToList" is that JOIN would be executed lazily, once per item, and each time it would build the mapping/join from scratch, while it is perfectly cacheable and reusable. Below, in expanded syntax, I explicitly pre-create the mapping only once, then all the other lazy queries without any materializations use share the same mapping. This way it may be several times faster and use less memory:

```
var mapping = eList.ToDictionary(x => x.id, x=>x.text);

var temps = sam.Select(s =>
    new {
        id = s.id,
        name = s.name,
        stringlist = s.list.Select(id => mapping[id]).OrderBy(str => str)
    });

var result = temps.OrderBy(t => t.stringlist.FirstOrDefault());
```

Comment: What I really want to achieve is 1st to sort the 'list' in list.  then after that it will return the sorted list in the 'sam' object. then now the 'sam' object will be sorted again my its list of object.

Comment: If I understand you well, it is already working like that. Please see the result dumps in my edited post

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var sorted = (from d1 in sam
              select new
              {
                  name = d1.name,
                  id = d1.id,
                  list =
                  (
                      from d2 in d1.list
                      join e in eList on d2 equals e.id
                      select e.text
                  )
              }).OrderBy(item => item.list.OrderBy(i => i).FirstOrDefault());
```